# Jstree onclick rename problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

Im reading a xml file i'd saved in the localStorage, using jstree. For the most of the features of jstree its working good, but i cant figure out how to edit in place the nodes just doing a click ove the label. i tried biding a click event over the

tag i have, but cant send the rename order to jstree function;

this is what i have, but its not working, please help me.

```
$(target).jstree({ 
"themes": {
"theme": "classic", 
"icons":false,
"dots":true 
},

"core": { 
"initially_open": [ "#hide" ],
"animation": 300 
}, 

"plugins": [ "themes", "html_data","dnd","crrm" ], 
"callback": { 
    "ondblclk": "function(n){alert()}"
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,its a standart bind functions

```
.bind("rename.jstree", function (e, data) {
        $.post(
            "./server.php", 
            { 
                "operation" : "rename_node", 
                "id" : data.rslt.obj.attr("id").replace("node_",""),
                "title" : data.rslt.new_name
            }, 
            function (r) {
                if(!r.status) {
                    $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
                }
            }
        );
    })
```